# Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException "/root/.composer/auth.json" does not contain valid JSON after installation

Tags: composer-php, ubuntu-18.04, vps

I've installed the composer on my ubuntu server by [instruction in download page](https://getcomposer.org/download/) to command-line installation.

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e0012edf3e80b6978849f5eff0d4b4e4c79ff1609dd1e613307e16318854d24ae64f26d17af3ef0bf7cfb710ca74755a') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

and for install globally followed [getting started](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) instruction:

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

after running commands I get:
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

```
Composer (version 1.10.4) successfully installed to: /root/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
```

but now when I enter composer command facing with this error:

```
  [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "/root/.composer/auth.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 1:

  ^
  Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

I tried `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --check` and get this:

```
All settings correct for using Composer
```

and when using `composer diagnose` getting the same error. tried to purge and reinstall but nothing changed:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove composer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'composer' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`/root/.composer/auth.json` file is empty

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What does that questioned file contain?

Comment: @NicoHaase I've edited the question.
know nothing about debugging of this

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you pretty much about the problem: the content of `/root/.composer/auth.json` is not valid JSON. If that file is empty, there is no need to keep it there - so either place your authentication details in that file or remove that file until you **need** it